# Is this sentence correct gramatically , especially " be excluded"?

Tags: subjunctives

Is this sentence correct grammatically, especially "be excluded"?

> It is surprising how Nenad Lalovich violates Olympic Charter and ignores the IOC recommending athletes from Russia and Belarus **be excluded** from international competition.

Comment: I've suggested a duplicate.  The use of "be" is a subjunctive.  You can use subjunctive with verbs like "recommend", "order", "insist" etc.

Comment: @ James K thank you so much.